# How to combine vectors of different length in a cell array into matrix in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, matrix, cell-array

How to efficiently combined cell array vectors with different length into a matrix, filling the vectors to max length with 0s or NaNs? It would be a nice option for `cell2mat()`.

For example, if I have

```
C = {1:3; 1:5; 1:4};
```

I'd like to get either

```
M = [1 2 3 0 0
     1 2 3 4 5
     1 2 3 4 0];
```

or

```
M = [1 2 3 NaN NaN
     1 2 3 4 5
     1 2 3 4 NaN];
```

Comment: Duplicate of [How can I accumulate cells of different lengths into a matrix in MATLAB?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3054437/how-can-i-accumulate-cells-of-different-lengths-into-a-matrix-in-matlab)

Comment: Yes! Thanks. Unfortunately I failed to find it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### EDIT:

For a cell of *row* vectors as in your case, this will pad vectors with zeros to form a matrix

```
out=cell2mat(cellfun(@(x)cat(2,x,zeros(1,maxLength-length(x))),C,'UniformOutput',false))

out =

     1     2     3     0     0
     1     2     3     4     5
     1     2     3     4     0
```

---

A [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6208526/matlab-concatenate-matrices-with-unequal-dimmensions) was asked earlier today, and although the question was worded slightly differently, [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6208526/matlab-concatenate-matrices-with-unequal-dimmensions/6208975#6208975) basically does what you want.

Copying the relevant parts here, a cell of uneven *column* vectors can be zero padded into a matrix as:

```
out=cell2mat(cellfun(@(x)cat(1,x,zeros(maxLength-length(x),1)),C,'UniformOutput',false));
```

where `maxLength` is assumed to be known. In your case, you have row vectors, which is just a slight modification from this.

If `maxLength` is not known, you can get it as

```
maxLength=max(cellfun(@(x)numel(x),C));
```

Comment: Thanks, @yoda. You almost made the one-liner code comparing with previous question. Unfortunately the first line does not work. And I'd change the maxLength finder to a simpler one: `maxLength = max(cellfun(@numel,x));` I'll look more into it.

Comment: @yuk: Why doesn't it work? As I mentioned, I wrote that for _column_ vectors, whereas you have row vectors here... If you make that change, it should work. I'll edit my question in a couple of minutes to add that in.