# Matlab: slow with converting date strings to datenum?

Tags: matlab

With 100,000 date strings to convert to datenums, Matlab is really slow... 20 seconds!!  Is there a faster way of doing this?

```
%strDay  
%strTime

dblDate = zeros(1, nLines);
for i = 1 : nLines
    dblDate(j) = datenum([strDay{i}, ' ', strTime{i}], 'yy.mm.dd HH:MM:SS.FFF');
    j = j + 1;
end
```

Comment: Unfortunately, `dblDate = cellfun(@(x,y) datenum([x,' ',y],'yy.mm.dd HH:MM:SS.FFF'),strDay,strTime,'UniformOutput',false)` takes 26 seconds.

Answer (score 4):

Internally, `datenum` does a large amount of fiddling around to process many different date formats. Then it calls the internal function `datenummx` with different input arguments depending on the date format and the syntax with which you called `datenum`.

If you know ahead of time which syntax you will be calling `datenum` with, and which date format you will be using, you can call `datenummx` directly. Since `datenummx` is a built-in MEX file, and avoids all the overhead processing, it is typically *vastly* faster.

Take a look into `datenum` (type `edit datenum`) to find out the appropriate way to call `datenummx` for your application.

(Plus, do all the vectorization that other answers have suggested).

Answer (score 2):

You could try to avoid the loop:

```
tmp = repmat({' '}, length(strDay), 1);
datenum(cell2mat([strDay  (:), tmp(:),  strTime(:)]))
```

**~edit~**
A little bit of benchmarking of all the solutions so far:

```
% creating some bogus data
a = ones(10000,1).*(now.*rand(10000,1));
str = datestr(a,'yy.mm.dd HH:MM:SS.FFF');
strDay = cellstr(str(:,1:8));
strTime = cellstr(str(:,10:end));

%% jdl's original code
disp('jdl''s original code')
tic
nLines = length(strDay);
dblDate = zeros(1, nLines);
j = 1;
for i = 1 : nLines
    dblDate(j) = datenum([strDay{i}, ' ', strTime{i}]);
    j = j + 1;
end
toc

%% hmuster's solution
disp('hmuster''s solution')
tic
tmp = repmat({' '}, length(strDay), 1);% cell(size(str1));
b = datenum(cell2mat([strDay(:), tmp(:),  strTime(:)]));
toc

%% ThijsW's solution
disp('ThijsW''s solution')
tic
strDay = cell2mat(strDay);
strTime = cell2mat(strTime);

dblDate = datenum([strDay, (' ')*ones(size(strTime)), strTime], 'yy.mm.dd HH:MM:SS.FFF');
toc

% jdl's solution
disp('jdl''s solution')
tic
dblDate = datenum(strDay, 'yy.mm.dd') + ...
    datenum(strTime, 'HH:MM:SS.FFF') - ...
    datenum('00:00:00.000', 'HH:MM:SS.FFF');
toc
```

This results in:

```
jdl's original code
   Elapsed time is 19.624597 seconds.
hmuster's solution
   Elapsed time is 4.029291 seconds.
ThijsW's solution
   Elapsed time is 0.183376 seconds.
jdl's solution
   Elapsed time is 0.222996 seconds.
```

Comment: issue with cell2mat... the date string coming can vary in width, ie: 3.5.12, 10.25.12 and will yield "Error using cat Dimensions of matrices being concatenated are not consistent. ", is there a work around? thx

Comment: Since your own solution is quite as fast as the one from ThijsW, you maybe should not bother with the `cell2mat` issue and simply use your own solution?

Comment: cell2mat is unique, good to use when lengths are the same.  Be nice to use for varying lengths as well.

Answer (score 2):

Try it without the for loop. `datenum` should be able to handle a vectors.

```
strDay = cell2mat(strDay);
strTime = cell2mat(strTime);

dblDate = datenum([strDay, (' ')*ones(size(strTime)), strTime], 'yy.mm.dd HH:MM:SS.FFF');
```

Comment: issue with cell2mat... the date string coming can vary in width, ie:  3.5.12, 10.25.12 and will yield "Error using cat
Dimensions of matrices being concatenated are not consistent.
", is there a work around? thx

Comment: You may want to check out this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6210495/how-to-combine-vectors-of-different-length-in-a-cell-array-into-matrix-in-matlab.
I'm not sure if padding with `' '` will give problems with datenum. Sorry, but I have no time to try it myself right now.

Answer (score 2):

This is what I found to reduce time from 20 sec to 2 sec:

```
dblDate = datenum(strDay, 'yy.mm.dd') + ...
          datenum(strTime, 'HH:MM:SS.FFF') - ...
          datenum('00:00:00.000', 'HH:MM:SS.FFF');
```