# Matlab playing Handel's Hallelujah no matter what sound i load

Tags: matlab

Can anyone tell me how to stop Handel's Hallelujah playing every time I load a different sound sample.

I am new to Matlab  and was working on sample code that loaded it as a .mat file  and I don't know how stop it from overriding everything else.

Comment: It would be much more helpful for you to post your actual code.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18773349/batch-reading-wav-files-in-matlab-to-create-a-matrix-for-neural-network-training     , see the solution to this question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Matlab includes a demo sample of Handel's Hallelujah Chorus. If you run

```
load handel;
```

The sample will be stored in the variable `y`. If you then create an `audio player`, you can use `play` to play the sample.

```
player = audioplayer(y, Fs);
play(player);
```

My guess (without seeing your code) is that your sample code loads and plays the handel sample as above.

**Solution: You need to find the offending lines and comment them out.**

---

Edit: Using code from https://stackoverflow.com/a/18773521/3303546

In a comment, you say you are using the code from this answer. On itsown, this code *does not* play any sounds. However, here are the possible locations where you might have added a `play` function.

**Spot 1:**

The first block creates two files: 'handel1.wav' and 'handel2.wav'

```
% create some data (write waves)
load handel.mat;                  %predifined sound in matlab stored in .mat
audiowrite('handel1.wav',y,Fs);   %write the first wave file
audiowrite('handel2.wav',y,Fs);   %write the second
clear y Fs                        %clear the data
```

As I described above, you can use `y` to play the sample at any point before the `clear` command. After the `clear` command and before any further code, it is not possible to play the sample.

**Spot 2:**

```
% reading section
filedir = dir('*.wav');           %list the current folder content for .wav file
Y = cell(1,length(filedir));      %pre-allocate Y in memory (edit from @ Werner)
FS = Y;                           %pre-allocate FS in memory (edit from @ Werner)
for ii = 1:length(filedir)        %loop through the file names

    %read the .wav file and store them in cell arrays
    [Y{ii,1}, FS{ii,1}] = audioread(filedir(ii).name);  

end
```

In or after the for-loop, you can play the sample with

```
player = audioplayer(Y{ind_wav,1}, Fs);
play(player);
```

Where `ind_wav` is either 1 or 2

**Spot 3:**

If you have run this code previously, the `Y` variable may still be in your workspace.

To remove it, run

```
clear Y
```

Comment: I have removed the  load handel.mat and loaded another m file [p,Fs] = audioread('a01.wav');
sound(p,Fs)        even this plays handel    in college i had to change machine.

Comment: Did you accidentally save the sample into the file 'a01.wav1'? If you play it with another program, does it contain the correct sound?

Comment: looks like i somehow overwritten 3 samples in my workstation, i deleted them and replaced them and everything  playing normally.   Thanks

Comment: That would do it. :)